# conditionally Coloring rows with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I work by `Apache poi` API, 
I want to color the lines conditionally , 
the rule is alternating color after 5 lines: the line 1-5 red, 
line 6-10 blue, line 11-15 red. so on.

this rule :

```
 ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("MOD(ROW(),2)");
```

alternate row in a different color.

how I can write my rule ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need two rules, one for red and one for blue.  Subtract 1 from `ROW()` so that row 11 becomes 10 and row 15 becomes 14, so that the result of the mod is less than 5.  Also, row 10 becomes 9 and the mod is greater than or equal to 5, so it will become blue.  The pattern repeats after 10 rows, so that's why the mod operand is `10`.

```
ConditionalFormattingRule red = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(
    "MOD(ROW() - 1, 10) < 5");
FontFormatting ffRed = red.createFontFormatting();
ffRed.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.RED.index);

ConditionalFormattingRule blue = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule(
    "MOD(ROW() - 1, 10) >= 5");
FontFormatting ffBlue = blue.createFontFormatting();
ffBlue.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.BLUE.index);
```

Then you can add the conditional formatting to your sheet with your `SheetConditionalFormatting` object, with an appropriate `CellRangeAddress`.

For more detail, see the [Quick Guide on Conditional Formatting](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ConditionalFormatting).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the following (or something similar, probably with `(ROW()+1)` or `(ROW()-1)` instead of `ROW()`) should work:

```
ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("MOD(ROW() / 5,2)");
```